# Catch Toggle(Play F7) button and prevent default action of Launching iTunes

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need to catch key pressed event and prevent it's default behavior: launch iTunes and toggle play and pause action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap